# easy way to link elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu that uses a sub-menu, that operates on a hide and show jquery function. The problem is that if I hover over a main-menu element, when I go to click on the sub-menu element it goes away. So I was wondering if I could make it that it only goes away if you arent hovering over the main menu element or the sub-menu block My website is http://www.spencedesign.netau.net/lori/#.

I also have another smaller issue, when the page is loaded the sub-menus are not hidden even though the css says `display: none;` I think it is the confusion between miking CSS `display: none;` and jQuery `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: where is your code snippet related to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this script was written, a submenu would only display (and continue displaying) while hovering over the main menu item.  As soon as you move off that item, the submenu will hide.

One simple solution is to include a check to see if you're hovering over that particular menu's submenu before executing the `hide()`.

[**example**](http://jsbin.com/useviz/1) // [**code**](http://jsbin.com/useviz/1/edit)

However, jquery doesn't really like it.  This solution *mostly* works in Chrome, but throws a few errors.

Despite this being a relatively straightforward menu, my recommendation here is to check out some jquery menu plugins.  There's no need to reinvent the wheel... even if you only need a simple wheel.

As for the second smaller issue, this is due to `display:none` being assigned to the sub_menu `id` (which doesn't exist on your page).  Make it a `class` instead and attach this class to each submenu div.

Comment: Awesome post thanks, and I don't see any errors in chrome